# Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'JsonDeserializer' could not be found (RestSharp v107)

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, restsharp

I get an error (after update RestSharp - v107) on the following line:

**`var contacts = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<List<Contact>>(response);`**

*Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'JsonDeserializer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using RestSharp;
using System.Text.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;

namespace ContactBook.ApiTests
{
public class ContactBookApiTests
{
    const string ApiBaseUrl = "URl/api";
    RestClient client;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        this.client = new RestClient(ApiBaseUrl);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test_ListContacts_CheckForSteveJobs()
    {
        // Arrange
        var request = new RestRequest("/contacts", Method.Get);

        // Act
        var response = this.client.ExecuteAsync(request);

        // Assert
        Assert.That(response.Status, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK));
        var contacts = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<List<Contact>>(response);
        Assert.That(contacts.Count, Is.GreaterThan(0));
        var firstContact = contacts[0];
        Assert.That(firstContact.firstName, Is.EqualTo("Steve"));
        Assert.That(firstContact.lastName, Is.EqualTo("Jobs"));
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var response = this.client.ExecuteAsync(request);
```

As the name suggests, this function returns `Task<RestResponse>`. You need to await the call.

There's also no need to explicitly deserialize the response, RestSharp will do it for you.

```
public async Task Test_ListContacts_CheckForSteveJobs() {
    var request = new RestRequest("/contacts", Method.Get);
    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<Contact[]>(request);
    var contacts = response.Data;

    // Assert
    Assert.That(response.Status, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK));
    Assert.That(contacts.Count, Is.GreaterThan(0));
    var firstContact = contacts[0];
    Assert.That(firstContact.firstName, Is.EqualTo("Steve"));
    Assert.That(firstContact.lastName, Is.EqualTo("Jobs"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 var response = this.client.ExecuteAsync(request).Result;

  //or better

var response = this.client.Execute(request);
....

 var contacts = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Contact>>(response.Content);
```

Comment: Thanks, but now response is highlighted in red.

Comment: @kzl-crw I updated my answer. Try again

Comment: Now content is highlighted in red.

Comment: @kzl-crw It should in the Upper case

Comment: It's the same..  hm

Comment: @kzl-crw I updated my answer again

Comment: With pleasure, but "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: @kzl-crw Just click a check mark on my answer side. and you already have enough reputation to vote too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241708/discussion-between-kzl-crw-and-serge).